# How to use input together with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need your help. I'm trying to make a todo-app using redux. Now I try to render data from input by means of redux. I can't create and paint items when I click a button.
Can you help me with this task, because I do not know how to use input with redux? In any case, here is a link to the project https://github.com/Dmytrii9Cherniak/inputs_redux Thank you

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {ADD_TODO} from "../Redux/Action_Types";

export let Tasks = () => {

let tasks = useSelector(state => state.tasks);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [addTask, setNewTask] = useState('');
const handleInput = (e) => {
    setNewTask(e.target.value)
}
const handleButton = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: ADD_TODO,
        payload: {
            id: Date.now(),
            label: addTask
        }
    })
}
return (<div>
        <input
            value={addTask}
            onChange={handleInput}
        />
        <button onClick={handleButton}>Create Todo</button>

        {tasks.map(el => <div key={el.id}>{el.label}</div>)}

        </div>)
}
```

Todo_Reducer.js

```
import {ADD_TODO, DELETE_TODO} from "./Action_Types";

const initialState = {
allTasks : []
}

const todo_reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {

case ADD_TODO: {
        return {
            ...state,
            allTasks: [...state.allTasks, action.payload]
        }
}

case DELETE_TODO: {
        return {
            ...state,
            allTasks: state.allTasks.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload)
        }
    }

default:
        return state;

   }
}
```

All_Reducers.js

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import todo_reducer from "./Todo_Reducer";

export let root_reducer = combineReducers({
todo_reducer
})
```

Action_types.js

```
let ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
let DELETE_TODO = 'DELETE_TODO'

export {ADD_TODO, DELETE_TODO}
```

Store.js

```
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {root_reducer} from "./All_Reducers";

export let store = createStore(root_reducer)
```

Comment: What you mean by "paint" items?

Comment: @jmargolisvt, create and show in the page

Comment: in the github repo you introduced, there isn't any code related to redux

Comment: @SaeedShamloo,I'm sorry, it already is. The folder is not loaded the first time

Comment: ok, let's check it

Comment: @Frankenstar Please check my answer, I checked your repo and found the problem is with your `useSelector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your repo, the problem is here:

```
// All_Reducers.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import todo_reducer from './Todo_Reducer';

export let root_reducer = combineReducers({
  todo_reducer,
});
```

as above combineReducers, your state shape will be like this:

```
state = {todo_reducer: { allTasks: [] } }
```

so, to fix your problem, update your useSelector in the Tasks component like this:

```
let tasks = useSelector((state) => state.todo_reducer.allTasks);
```